# Expected value of multiplied and squared Wiener Process

Tags: finance, expectation

Can someone help me how to calculate the following:

$E0[z^2[2] \mathrm{Exp}[-2 z[2]] ]$

Where $z[2]$ is Wiener process. How to find exact expected value?  I am new to this stuff and not sure how to do this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you redefine what $z[2]$ is? The value of a Wiener process at time 2?